# How to group a dataframe with 2 columns and get highest count?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (df). Col A is a category and Col B is an item in that category.

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| red | car |
| red | car |
| red | truck |
| red | ball |
| blue | bus |
| blue | bus |
| blue | bus |
| blue | truck |
| blue | car |

I want to get another dataframe (df2) showing the total count of distinct categories in Col A, followed by the count highest occurring item in Col B corresponding to Col A as below:

| Col A | Count A | Col B | Count B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 4 | car | 2 |
| blue | 5 | bus | 2 |

Any idea on how to generate this dataframe?

I have tried this command:

df2 = df.groupby('Col A')['Col B'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()

and I get the following result:

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| red | car |
| blue | bus |

I don't know how to get the two counts column. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried pivot_table? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)** from **Collections**:

```
from collections import Counter
final = df.groupby(['Col A']).agg({'Col A':'count','Col B':list})

'''
       Col A                        Col B
Col A                                    
blue       5  [bus, bus, bus, truck, car]
red        4      [car, car, truck, ball]
'''

final['Col_b'] = final['Col B'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]) #get most common value
final['Count_b'] = final['Col B'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][1]) #get count of most common value
final=final.drop('Col B',axis=1).rename(columns={'Col A':'Count A'}).reset_index()
```

**Output**:

```
|    | Col A   |   Count A | Col_b   |   Count_b |
|---:|:--------|----------:|:--------|----------:|
|  0 | blue    |         5 | bus     |         3 |
|  1 | red     |         4 | car     |         2 |
```